# Keeping output stream open

Tags: java, io, codenameone, flush

I wonder how to deal with `OutputStream`s in codenameone, which have to be kept open for a long time. There are many places, where they get written and it's be neither efficient nor error-proof to try to flush the stream everywhere. So I wrote this:

```
private boolean needsFlush;

private void write(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    assert Display.getInstance().isEdt();
    out.write(data);
    if (!needsFlush) {
        needsFlush = true;
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(this::flush);
    }
}

private void flush() {
    try {
        out.flush();
        needsFlush = false;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); // UGLY!
    }
}
```

which should ensure that after every write, there'll be a flush sometime. Unless the app gets closed or alike.... that's why I need to ask.

- Is it OK? Is there's better way of handling stream flushing?
- Do they closed then properly, when the app gets terminated?
- Do I have to add stream closing code to `stop()` of the "main" class?
- Or only to `destroy()`?
- What about the ugly try-catch?

Comment: You only need to flush when you are about to read a response. If that doesn't answer your question it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user207421 I don't need to read it until next start. So you think that not flushing the stream is safe? You may be right...., but do you have any evidence?

Comment: @user207421 On the second thought.... while `FileOutputStream` may need no flushing as it gets closed when program terminates, there's buffering in my streams and I can't rely on getting called when the app get closed/killed. Or can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest closing the output stream on `stop()` and re-opening it on `start()`. Notice that if the stream points to `FileSystemStorage` you can append to the end of the stream using CN's: `OutputStream os = openFileOutputStream(filePath, lengthOfFile);`.

You need to close on `stop()` as the app is sent to the background. In that state you should avoid open connections as they might be terminated suddenly by the OS. The entire app can be killed because of a wayward stream.

If you have background support in the app you should open and close the stream every time you need it.

Comment: This sounds good, but opens two side questions: 1. Can I make the simulator invoke `stop()` and `start()`? 2. When my process gets killed, does the previous `flush` ensure no data gets lost?

Comment: Another question: Are the `FileSystemStorage` streams somehow buffered or should I add buffering myself?

Comment: Sure, suspend/resume in the simulator menu triggers `stop()`/`start()`. Flush writes to the disk so it gives a "good chance" but "guarantees" is a string word. All streams in Codename One are buffered by default.